# grep command in curl

Tags: grep

I am trying to extract some URLs from a web page using cURL command. Initially, I use the cURL command as below.

```
curl www.website.com/
```

Now, the website contains links to some other websites which am interested in extracting. So, I do a grep on the cURL command as below.

```
curl www.website.com/ | grep "<a href=" > new1.txt
```

It is extracting all lines which have `<a href=` in them. But am particularly interested only in lines which start with `<a href=` and end with `title=`

How can I modify the grep command?

Comment: If that's all you need, you can do `grep "<a href=.*title="` but this can get complicated when parsing HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
curl www.website.com/ | grep '^<a href=.*title=$' > new1.txt
```

This will select all lines that begin with `<a href=` and end in `title=`

Just saw Terdon's comment. You can use `-P` option with grep and make a `non-greedy` aka `lazy` alternative as follows:

```
curl www.website.com/ | grep -P '^<a href=.*?title=$' > new1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind that [HTML is *not* a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la), and parsing it with regular expressions is nigh-impossible, you could try:

```
... | grep '^<a href=.*title=.*' > ...
```

**Edit:** Saw that you specified lines that *start* with `<a href`; the caret takes care of that condition.